# Cascade valued down a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(~urn, ~year, ~retained, ~retained_years,
        1, 2010, 0, 0,
        1, 2011, 1, 1,
        1, 2012, 1, 2,
        1, 2013, 1, 3,
        1, 2014, 1, 4,
        2, 2010, 0, 0,
        2, 2011, 1, 1,
        2, 2013, 0, 0,
        2, 2014, 1, 1)

# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#     urn  year retained retained_years
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1  2010        0              0
# 2     1  2011        1              1
# 3     1  2012        1              2
# 4     1  2013        1              3
# 5     1  2014        1              4
# 6     2  2010        0              0
# 7     2  2011        1              1
# 8     2  2013        0              0
# 9     2  2014        1              1
```

I am wanting to add a column using `dplyr` that creates a new column `ret_year_start` that populates with the minimum year for a group of records where the value of `retained` = 1. The results would look like the following dataset.

```
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#     urn  year retained retained_years ret_year_start
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     1  2010        0              0             NA
# 2     1  2011        1              1           2011
# 3     1  2012        1              2           2011
# 4     1  2013        1              3           2011
# 5     1  2014        1              4           2011
# 6     2  2010        0              0             NA
# 7     2  2011        1              1           2011
# 8     2  2013        0              0             NA
# 9     2  2014        1              1           2014
```

I've tried grouping by different things, however it isn't so much the grouping rather the set of sequences that I want to set a starting year for.

I know it's not so much a code diagnostic question as it is a code vocabulary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'run' and the run-length-id (`rleid` from `data.table` of 'retained', and get the 'year' that corresponds to the first element position of retained with 1

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(urn, grp = rleid(retained)) %>%
   mutate(ret_year_start = year[which(retained==1)[1]])
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   urn, grp [6]
#    urn  year retained retained_years   grp ret_year_start
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl> <int>          <dbl>
#1     1  2010        0              0     1             NA
#2     1  2011        1              1     2           2011
#3     1  2012        1              2     2           2011
#4     1  2013        1              3     2           2011
#5     1  2014        1              4     2           2011
#6     2  2010        0              0     3             NA
#7     2  2011        1              1     4           2011
#8     2  2013        0              0     5             NA
#9     2  2014        1              1     6           2014
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, ret_year_start := year[which(retained==1)[1]], .(rleid(retained), urn)]
```

Comment: I knew it was a vocabulary issue. The `rleid` functions one I've not come across before. I suspect it's worth investigating further.